# MO diagram of N2(2-)

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

In the MO diagram of $\ce{N2^2-}$, does s-p mixing happen to a significant degree to change the ordering of orbitals - $\pi_\mathrm{2p}$ orbital below $\sigma_\mathrm{2p}$? As it is isoelectronic with oxygen, I think that the s-p mixing shouldn't change the ordering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to test [whether there may be $\ce{s}$-$\ce{p}$ mixing](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/24663/40029) and also to check [whether there may be actually a bound state](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/26500/40029), I optimised this molecule (at PBE0-D3/def2-TZVPD) using NWChem 6.6 and analysed it using natural bonding orbitals (NBO 5.9).
I found following minimum geometry:

[image: N2-2]

**Figure 1**: Minimum geometry found for $\ce{N2^{-2}}$ (distance in angstrom)

So there seems to be a bound state.

Natural charge on each $\ce{N}$ is -1.0 as would be expected (natural electron configuration was found to be $\ce{1s^{2.00} 2s^{1.65} 2p^{4.17} 3s^{0.06} 3p^{0.05} 3d^{0.07} 4d^{0.01}}$).
Wiberg bond order in the NAO basis for the $\ce{N-N}$ bond was found to be 2.2511.

Two bonding NBOs were found:

```
    (Occupancy)   Bond orbital/ Coefficients/ Hybrids
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1. (2.00000) BD ( 1) N  1- N  2
              ( 50.00%)   0.7071* N  1 s(  0.00%)p 1.00( 99.74%)d 0.00(  0.24%)
                                                 f 0.00(  0.02%)
              ( 50.00%)   0.7071* N  2 s(  0.00%)p 1.00( 99.74%)d 0.00(  0.24%)
                                                 f 0.00(  0.02%)
  2. (2.00000) BD ( 2) N  1- N  2
              ( 50.00%)   0.7071* N  1 s( 36.78%)p 1.70( 62.66%)d 0.01(  0.51%)
                                                 f 0.00(  0.06%)
              ( 50.00%)   0.7071* N  2 s( 36.78%)p 1.70( 62.66%)d 0.01(  0.51%)
                                                 f 0.00(  0.06%)
```

That is,

$$\pi_{\ce{N1-N2}} = 0.7071 \ce{p}_{\ce{N1}} + 0.7071 \ce{p}_{\ce{N2}}$$

[image: pi bond]

**Figure 2**: $\pi_{\ce{N1-N2}}$ bond of $\ce{N2^{-2}}$

$$\sigma_{\ce{N1-N2}} = 0.7071 \ce{sp^{1.70}}_{\ce{N1}} + 0.7071 \ce{sp^{1.70}}_{\ce{N2}}$$

[image: sigma bond]

**Figure 3**: $\sigma_{\ce{N1-N2}}$ bond of $\ce{N2^{-2}}$

Furthermore,

```
NATURAL BOND ORBITALS (Summary):

                                                    Principal Delocalizations
          NBO                 Occupancy    Energy   (geminal,vicinal,remote)
===============================================================================
Molecular unit  1  (N2)
  1. BD ( 1) N  1- N  2        2.00000     0.18488
  2. BD ( 2) N  1- N  2        2.00000    -0.43475  10(g),42(g)
```

**Thus, according to the simple Lewis picture provided by NBO**,

1. $\ce{s}$-$\ce{p}$ mixing ($\ce{sp^{1.70}-sp^{1.70}}$) happens for the formation of $\sigma_{\ce{N1-N2}}$, as expected;
2. the formation of $\pi_{\ce{N1-N2}}$ *happens through pure $p$ hybrids*; and
3. $\pi_{\ce{N1-N2}}$ lies in energy *above* $\sigma_{\ce{N1-N2}}$ by 0.61963 a.u..

Comment: According to "Experimental Search for the Smallest Stable Multiply Charged Anions in the Gas Phase" Physical Review Letters vol. 83, page 3402: "It has
also been concluded that no diatomic or triatomic dianions
are stable" http://casey.brown.edu/chemistry/research/LSWang/publications/84.pdf

Comment: And Physical Review A vol. 60, page 3515 says "Theoretical
attempts to understand the stability of the dianions already
discovered and directed towards finding ever smaller molecules
capable of supporting two extra electrons soon followed
[18–30]. A summary of the status of these calculations
is given in Scheller, Compton, and Cederbaum [31]. To
date, the smallest molecular dianions calculated to be stable
are alkali-metal halides of the form MX3
-2 (M=Li, Na, or
K; X=F or Cl)" http://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.60.3515

Comment: **You are completely right**, this is highly unstable, as thoroughly supported by the articles provided [and](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ar960147o) [further](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.464978) [citations](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.79.1237) [therein](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.81.5302).
In fact it has been stated, "a molecular dianion (such as a diatomic) must be stable not only with respect to the ejection of an extra electron but also to fragmentation" ([ref. 31](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.270.5239.1160) of your second citation).

Comment: Thus, either $\ce{[N2]^{-2} -> [N2]^{-1} + e^-}$ (and maybe even $\ce{[N2]^{-1} -> N2 + e^-}$, I'm not sure) or $\ce{[N2]^{-2} -> 2 N^{-1}}$ (or $\ce{[N2]^{-2} -> N^{-2} + N}$?) is a favourable, spontaneous process.
This, in turn, is due to very low transition states (fast processes) and/or very stable products.
**But I have not claimed stability**, but the existence of a bound state.
At the level of theory applied, I found one bound state and analysed its wavefunction. No more, no less.

Comment: The singly-negative charged $\ce{N2-}$  has been calculated as bound between lengths 1.4 and 2.5 Angstroms http://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.478408 , so I'm surprised that adding another negative charge would make the bond length shorter and still be bound.

Comment: Also N2(2-) has a triplet GS, while the answer seems to imply a singlet one.

Answer (score 5):

Well, s-p mixing only occurs when the s and p atomic orbitals are close in energy (it's a necessary but not sufficient condition). Even though $\rm N_2^{2-}$ is isoelectronic with $\rm O_2$, the lower effective nuclear charge on nitrogen should make its s orbitals a little closer to the energies of the p orbitals than they would be in oxygen. I think you still *would* have s-p mixing.

Clarification: I mean to cast doubt on the conjecture that there's no s-p mixing here. As you point out in the comments, electron repulsion is a consideration too. We can't definitively say which effect is more important without looking at the actual orbital energies.

Comment: But the two added electrons would cause big repulsion forces, which would increase the difference in energy between s and p, right?

Comment: There would be some additional repulsion which would increase the difference, but those two added electrons go in different orbitals, so it wouldn't be that big a difference. Really we'd have to look at the actual orbital energies to answer your question definitively.

Comment: I would be delighted if I could get an accurate answer.

Comment: @FredSenese  Fred wrote, "Well, s-p mixing only occurs when the s and p atomic orbitals are close in energy."  It doesn't always occur even then.  The lone pairs in water are an example.  One lone pair is basically in a p orbital and the other in an sp orbital.  That's very different from what was (still is) taught.  S-P mixing is difficult (impossible?) to predict without experimental data such as molecular shape, ESCA (for lone pairs), etc.  In addition to the water example, s-p mixing in NH3 and PH3 is different, how would you predict this difference without experimental data?

Comment: @ron, in your NH3/PH3 example, what role would the different effective nuclear charges play on the difference in energy between s and p orbitals? Wouldn't that predict the difference?

Comment: @FredSenese  It doesn't seem to be taught that way, many people learn that PH3 is tetrahedral like NH3.  But following up on your point, due to more nuclear screening in P than N, wouldn't the 3s and 3p orbitals be expected to be closer in energy and therefore more likely to mix (hybridize)?  Just the opposite of what is observed.

Comment: Well, *I* don't teach that PH3 is tetrahedral---it's not. And the effective nuclear charges for 2s/2p in nitrogen are 3.847/3.834, and for 3s/3p in phosphorus they're 5.642/4.886 (I'm using Clementi's numbers here). So wouldn't the situation be a bigger separation in P, and in accord with what's observed?

Comment: @FredSenese Yes, based on those numbers.  Water is still a problem.  Why do the 2 OH bonds and one of the lone pairs hybridize and the other lone pair doesn't.  I'm still skeptical that s-p mixing can be predicted by simple methodologies.

Comment: We agree on that, actually; I just wanted to provide a counter argument for Marko's assertion that there wasn't any s-p mixing. Electron correlation needs to be accurately included in the calculation to see and understand effects like that...  When I'm back on campus I'll do a quick search for some $\rm N_2^{2-}$ calculations that include electron correlation; if I find anything I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It don't think that $\ce{N2^{2-}}$ can exist as a free species.

$\ce{N-}$ is unstable.  In other words, the electron affinity of nitrogen is negative.

To create $\ce{N2^{2-}}$ you would need to bring together 2 negatively charged $\ce{N-}$ which are each already unstable due to their negative charge.

According to [Experimental Search for the Smallest Stable Multiply Charged Anions in the Gas Phase](http://casey.brown.edu/chemistry/research/LSWang/publications/84.pdf) *Physical Review Letters* vol. 83, page 3402:

> It has also been concluded that no diatomic or triatomic dianions are stable

Comment: And how is this relevant to the question?

Comment: @user34388 If there is no bound state of the ion, how can it be modeled using linear combinations of bound atomic orbitals such as s and p?

Comment: Fair enough....